# How to OverlayService Fullscreen?

Tags: android, service, overlay, fullscreen, window-managers

```
     wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
     int type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
     int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
     int format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
     WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            type, flags, format);
     params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
     wm.addView(lockScreenView, params);
```

I tried to use **`FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMIT`** or **`FLAG_FULLSCREEN`**. But it's only available on devices that have a hard home button. They are unavailable in devices have a **navigation bar** or **virtual keyboard**.